# Why the has property not working on my browser?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a big Java Web Application and I would like to add a css property but its not working.

This is my simple code (HTML):

```css
div:has(p) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Prueba</p>
</div>
```

The objective is the background color of `Prueba` to be red color, but not working.
Can you help me for to resolve this problem? I would like to be refference to the `div` with the `p` .

Answer (score 1):

`:has` is a CSS level 4 selector, and *will not* be implemented in CSS, only in JS `querySelector` and similar.

This is the case as `:has()` is *not* a "dynamic profile", unlike every other selector. It won't be implemented in CSS, as "implementations conformant to Selectors Level 4 must use the dynamic profile" [[source](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#profiles)]

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, `:has` has no support in any browser and is an experimental technology:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has
- https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has

<strike>I don't see why `div > p` wouldn't suit your needs.</strike>

Comment: he wants the `div` with the `p`

Answer (score 0):

`:has` is a property *proposed* for [CSS Selectors level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational).

It isn't [supported by browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has) because it is too new.

Comment: Actually, that's not why. It likely won't be implemented in CSS, at least not in the near future, as it's a "static profile", basically meaning it's too performance-intensive.